# Where do I put the Spinner Code when uploading files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, file-upload

I have searched and searched and just can't seem to find the right solution or it's right in front of me and haven't figured it out.

I have a form where the users of the site will be selecting files (based on a "file" input).  There are 6 different file inputs and the files are uploaded to Dropbox through cURL with one submit button.  So what I want is a spinner that will show until all the files are uploaded.

The form code looks like this...

```
<form id="upload" class="formcenter" action="includes/upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In the "includes/upload.inc.php" file it has the code to upload to dropbox and then once everything is uploaded I use a...

```
    header("Location: ../uploadResult.php");
```

to redirect them to a different page to let them know if the upload was successful or not.

I am using a Bootstrap Spinner for the spinner and I added some text below it...

The code for that is...

```
    </head>
    <style>
    .myspinner {
     height: 100vh;
     display:flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     }

    </style>
    <body>

    <div class="myspinner">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="spinner-border text-danger" role="status">
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
    </div>
    <p style="text-align: center;"> Uploading... </p>
    </div>
```

The problem is that I do not know where to put it while everything is uploading.

What I did first was go to the "includes/upload.inc.php" file and comment out all of the php code, and added the above spinner code above the php code, went back to my form, chose a file and clicked the "Upload Documents" submit button.  As we would assume, it sent me to the "inlcudes/upload.inc.php" file and the spinner worked perfectly.  It blanked out the page and the spinner was in the center with the "Uploading..." below it.

So my next thought was to uncomment the php code and then when I submitted the form again I would get the spinner while it was uploading since the  was above the php and then when it redirected after upload it would end because it's on a different page.  But that was not the case at all.  It stayed on the form page while it was uploading and then when it was finished it went to the "uploadResult.php" page.  So the spinner was never seen.

And this is where I get confused... if it worked without the php code, why isn't it working with the php?  Do I need to add the spinner code on the form file instead? Or do i need to have some other kind of code in the "includes/upload.inc.php" file.

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to have the spinner on the page with the form but hidden. Handle the form submission with javascript and have it show the spinner.

Comment: Thank you Taylor!  Your answer helped push me in the right direction to search for onsubmit and turning on and off display in Javascript and now it's working exactly how I want! Thank you again!